# Parser JSON ON QT

Tags: c++, json, qt

Is it possible to use an operator **||** in json like this :

```
{
"ven":{
    "source":"logicCtrl" ,
     "msg":"radio_volume" || "radio-mute", || "radio3",
     "type":"int"
      }
}
```

i can after  get data by parsing data in C++ side like this :

```
QFile jsonFile("VenParser.json");
if (!jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    qDebug() << "problème d'overture du fichier, exit";

}

QByteArray jsonData = jsonFile.readAll();

QJsonParseError *err = new QJsonParseError();

QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonData, err);

if (err->error != 0)
    qDebug() << err->errorString();

Venparser myparser;

if (doc.isNull())
{
    qDebug() << "Document invalide";

}
else if (doc.isObject())
{
    //recuperer l'object json
    QJsonObject jObject = doc.object();

    //convertir l'object json to variantmap
    QVariantMap mainMap = jObject.toVariantMap();

    // variant map
    QVariantMap Map = mainMap["ven"].toMap();

    myparser.source = Map["source"].toString();
    myparser.msg =  Map["msg"].toString();
    myparser.type = Map["type"].toString();
```

header.H file : i define my struct

```
struct Venparser {
    QString source;
    QString msg;
    QString type;
```

My problem is that i don't want a list in my "msg" but something like this :

when i call **myparser.msg** , then it will check just the value i need in **msg** and return it.

**"msg":"radio_volume" || "radio-mute", || "radio3",**

Thanks,

Comment: Firstly, that's nowhere near valid JSON. Secondly, what on earth is it supposed to mean?!

Comment: how can i do somehting like this ! i know it not valid.

Comment: Something like *what*? What's the goal? What does ‘string or string or string’ mean? What do you expect to get from `Map["msg"].toString()`?

Comment: when i will use myparser.msg in c++ part and give the right value like "radio_volume" , it will ouput "msg": "radio_volume" . it it possible in json ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: i know i get an error cause i does not exist in json that why i am asking how to do it .if it was a list it will work but  i don't want a list in my case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132370/discussion-between-ismaela-d-and-biffen).

Comment: Ok, so if i define something like that  : {
"ven":{
    "source":"logicCtrl" ,
     "msg":["radio_volume" ,"radio-mute", "radio3"],
     "type":"int"
}  is there a way to acces to each data of msg

Comment: Yes, of course there is. It's an array. You can iterate over all of its elements or access them individually using their indices.

Comment: How can do it ? iterate over all of its elements ? or using indice.do you have example ? thanks

Comment: It depends on the library used. Look it up in their documentation.

Comment: Ok ! thanks, i will look to the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example with the `||` token is not a valid JSON. You can read more about its format [here](http://json.org). However, if I understand you correctly, you can easily use JSON arrays for your task.

#### JSON:

```
{
  "ven": {
    "source": "logicCtrl",
    "msg": ["radio_volume", "radio-mute", "radio3"],
    "type": "int"
  }
}
```

#### C++:

You can access the `msg` array using the `toStringList()` method. Also, you can use `QVariantList` and `toList()` respectively if you fill your array with data different from strings.

```
QStringList messages = Map["msg"].toStringList();
```

Now the `messages` variable contains *"radio_volume"*, *"radio-mute"* and *"radio3"* values so you can extract the required string any way you need using your code.

---

If you still need to parse your exact example (which is technically not a valid JSON as I said before), you will have to go with writing your own parser, which is a bit wide topic for the answer.

Comment: this, in my case can do the work ! i don't really need my own parser. thanks @kerfir500.